# No matching function for call to "MessageDlg"

Tags: c++, c++builder

I am receiving an error indicating that their is no matching function for a call to `MessageDlg()` in C++ Builder.

My header file does include `<Vcl.Dialogs.hpp>` which is where the function is declared. The function is being called from within a `TForm` class public function. Below is the offending code:

```
void MBInvalidPosition() {
    MessageDlg("Invalid Position Selected. Please Try Again",
        mtError,mbOK,0);
}
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ supports overloaded functions — which function you're calling is a product of both its name and the types of the arguments supplied to it. Therefore, given that you have the correct name of a function, a reasonable first guess is that you are supplying the wrong type for one of the arguments.

Specifically, it doesn't look like `mbOK` can be supplied raw like that — `MessageDlg` wants a third argument of type `TMsgDlgButtons` but `mbOK` is of type `TMsgDlgBtn`. The appropriate way to create a set of buttons that includes only the OK button is `TMsgDlgButtons() << mbOK`. So:

```
void MBInvalidPosition() {
    MessageDlg("Invalid Position Selected. Please Try Again",
        mtError,TMsgDlgButtons() << mbOK,0);
}
```

Comment: Also, just an FYI - since XE2+ is being used, the 1st parameter will expect a `UnicodeString`, but a narrow string literal (`const char[44]`) is being passed in instead. While that will "work" fine, it does involve an ANSI->Unicode conversion at runtime. To avoid that overhead, you should provide a Unicode string literal, ie: `MessageDlg(L"...", ...)` or better `MessageDlg(_D("..."), ...)`

Comment: @Tommy. Thanks for the clue. It worked like a charm. As newbie to C+ Builder I didn't know you could not pass the direct button ID. Thanks.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thanks for the tip.